# Can a UK 3DS play USA DS Titles?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-series, region-lock

I want to buy Pokemon Soul Silver, a USA version, in order to play it on my 3DS. I know the 3DS is region locked, but is it region locked for DS games? Need an answer generally or specifically for USA on a UK 3DS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nintendo DS line does not have region locking for physical cartridges.

Comment: So it would work on a 3DS?

Comment: It should. I can't guarantee things for you, but according to sources the DS cartridges are not region-locked.

Comment: Alright then, thank you. I guess I can just refund it if it doesn't work!

Comment: @Joe Only Pokemon B2W2 should be [region locked on DSi and 3DS models](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/).